# Is possible insert multiple function inside component in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a component in angular js

```
 app.component('phoneDetail', {
     templateUrl: 'new.html',
     controller: ['$http','$routeParams',
       function PhoneDetailController($http,$routeParams) {
         var valueX = this;


         $http.get('http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/phones/'+ $routeParams.valueX + '.json').then(function(response){
            valueX.phone = response.data;
         });
       }]
 });
```

i need to insert another function like onclick()

```
 $scope.littleSize = false;

 $scope.toggleSize = function() {
     $scope.littleSize = !$scope.littleSize;
```

is possible insert inside on this component or i must create another component ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put as much function as you want into a controller. It is up to you to separate them in a way that makes sense.

So this is okay:

```
app.component('phoneDetail', {
     templateUrl: 'new.html',
     controller: ['$http','$routeParams',
       function PhoneDetailController($http,$routeParams) {
          var controller = this;
          $http.get('http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/phones/'+ $routeParams.valueX + '.json').then(function(response){
            controller.phone = response.data;
          });
          controller.onClick = function() { console.log("I am clicked"); }
     }]
});
```

new.html

```
<div>
    <span>{{ $ctrl.phone }}</span>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.onClick()">Click me</button>
</div>
```

I hope I get the question right.

Comment: i have  this function $scope.littleSize = false;

$scope.toggleSize = function() {
    $scope.littleSize = !$scope.littleSize;  with $scope my application not run, how i can put inside component ?

Comment: You can use the value of this (valueX in your code sample controller in my code sample) instead of $scope. e.g. `controller.littleSite = false; controller. toggleSize = function() ...` and in view `$ctrl.toggleSize()`.

Comment: on the div i have  <img  ng-click="toggleSize()" ng-class="{little:littleSize, big:!littleSize}" it change value on css, i must change something ?

Comment: i have change function in this controller. doTheBack = function() {
              $window.history.back(); }  i'd like to create a button for go back  but not run